# How can I fix the error on this file appconfig-data.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Referenced file contains errors (project-aware://registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mssql/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/
 spring-tool-4.2.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

File appconfig-data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: this project downloaded and import in eclipse to run,  i don't know fixed it but run project success. thank you so much!!!